# To understand MySQL's error messages in OS X

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

I am reading [MySQL's manuals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-macosx-excerpt/5.0/en/mac-os-x-installation.html).

I run

```
. /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql                                                                                                                            ~
```

I get

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql:1: command not found: ????^G
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql:2: permission denied: 
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql:3: parse error near `}'
```

I run

```
. /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin                                                                                                                         ~
```

I get

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin:9: parse error near `)'
```

These error messages suggest me that my MySQL seems to be corrupted.
I did not found by Google explanations for the error messages.

**What do the messages really mean?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try running

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

[without the dot]

if you use "dot space" at the beginning file you provide path to will be interpreted as bash-script, but what you point is actual binary executable, not a script.

what you try is **NOT** the way to start mysql server, those are attempts to run mysql client.

Comment: I get the error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Comment: that is much better. do you have mysqld [ mysql server ] running ?

Comment: The other command seems to work without "." --- I do not understand how you can run a file without "."

Comment: @pQd: I do not have it running, since I have this problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/35859/unable-to-start-a-mysql-server-on-mac-os-x/35967#35967

Comment: but what you try to run is mysql client [ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql ], mysql server is usually called mysqld or mysqld_safe.

Comment: i dont really know mac os, but i don't think you can run for instance . /bin/ls [ path might differ ]. i might bet wrong.

Comment: @Masi do not run mysqld with & just open another console and let it sit there, run mysqld --verbose - maybe you'll get some more useful error msgs.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/36052/what-is-the-purpose-of-source-as-a-shell-command for a discussion of "the dot".